# DataFrame creation from dict & index order?

Tags: pandas, dictionary, python-3.7

I am using a recent download of Anaconda with Python 3.7.1 & pandas 0.23.4

The [pandas doc](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/getting_started/dsintro.html) says:

> When the data is a dict, and an index is not passed, the Series index will be ordered by the dict’s insertion order

I instantiate a pandas DataFrame from a dict with no index passed:

```
newspapers = {'Jim':{'Mon':15,'Tue':17,'Wed':21,'Thu':16,'Fri':19},\
     'Tony':{'Mon':8,'Tue':15,'Wed':11,'Thu':16,'Fri':13}, \
     'Colin':{'Mon':13,'Tue':17,'Wed':19,'Thu':17,'Fri':20} \
    }
newspapers_df = pd.DataFrame(newspapers)
```

Why does this not show in insertion order, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri?:

```
print(newspapers_df)
```

outputs:

```
      Jim  Tony  Colin
Fri   19    13     20
Mon   15     8     13
Thu   16    16     17
Tue   17    15     17
Wed   21    11     19
```

Comment: What is your version of pandas as this behaviour was introduced for a specific version

Comment: You should raise bugs on [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues) as it's more appropriate there

Comment: Updated post for v0.23.4. 
I was not sure I found a bug, I thought I was missing something

Comment: This looks like a bug to me, I would post an issue as it should work

Comment: raised issue #[25911](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25911) @edChum, thanks, can you turn your comment into an answer please?

Comment: I don't think I need to, to be honest. For me this is a bug, there are many workarounds but the real question is why doesn't this work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems bug, for me working in python 3.5, pandas 0.24.2 create `Series` in dictionary comprehension and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
newspapers_df = pd.DataFrame({k:pd.Series(v) for k, v in newspapers.items()})

print (newspapers_df)
     Jim  Tony  Colin
Mon   15     8     13
Tue   17    15     17
Wed   21    11     19
Thu   16    16     17
Fri   19    13     20
```

---

Possible solutions with your data - [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) or `ordered CategoricalIndex`:

```
newspapers_df = pd.DataFrame(newspapers)

L = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri']
newspapers_df = newspapers_df.reindex(L)
```

Or:

```
newspapers_df.index = pd.CategoricalIndex(newspapers_df.index, ordered=True, categories=L)
newspapers_df = newspapers_df.sort_index()
print (newspapers_df)
     Jim  Tony  Colin
Mon   15     8     13
Tue   17    15     17
Wed   21    11     19
Thu   16    16     17
Fri   19    13     20
```

Comment: Yes, sorting, passing an index works fine thanks, but this was not the question

Comment: @boardtc - yes, so first paragraph working? I think only outer ditionary are processes correctly, deeper not.

Comment: newspapers_df in your first paragraph prints as you show for me too.

I can raise a bug on pandas-dev guthub.

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25911 opened but community did not wish to fix

Answer (score 2):

The same sorting could be done using [numpy.argsort()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
days_dict = {'Mon':0, 'Tue':1,'Wed':2,'Thu':3,'Fri':4,'Sat':5,'Sun':6}
df = pd.DataFrame(newspapers).reset_index()
df.iloc[np.argsort(df['index'].map(days_dict)),:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks the pd.Series and pd.DataFrame has different way to handle the case.

I has similar python environment and the result could be replicated in my computer. Also, the Jezrel's pd.Series case could be replicated in my computer.

I check the manual and found both result are folllow the doc.

For series, the key is **index**
When the data is a dict, and an index is not passed, the **Series index** will be **ordered by the dict’s insertion order**, if you’re using Python version >= 3.6 and Pandas version >= 0.23.

For dataframe: the key is column.
If **axis labels** are not passed, they will be constructed from the input data based on **common sense rules**.

Note When the data is a dict, and columns is not specified, the **DataFrame columns** will be ordered by the dict’s insertion order, if you are using Python version >= 3.6 and Pandas >= 0.23.

That means, if you want to make sure both columns and index sort, you might need pass index or sort them later.

Hope it answer you question.

Comment: The answer was that there is a bug in pandas!